# How do I make an array of Comparables

Tags: java, comparable

I am trying to make arrays of objects that implement the Comparable interface.
The object of the project is to merge two presorted arrays, of Comparable type, into a single
sorted array. So far I have:

```
public Comparable[] mergeArrays(Comparable[] arrayOne, Comparable[] arrayTwo){
    
    Comparable[] merged = new Comparable[arrayOne.length + arrayTwo.length];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    
    for(int k = 0; k < merged.length; ++k) {
        if(i >= arrayOne.length) {
            merged[k] = arrayTwo[j];
            ++j;
        }
        else if(j >= arrayTwo.length) {
            merged[k] = arrayOne[i];
            ++i;
        }
        else {
            if(arrayOne[i].compareTo(arrayTwo[j]) > 0) {
                merged[k] = arrayTwo[j];
                ++j;
            }
            else if(arrayOne[i].compareTo(arrayTwo) < 0) {
                merged[k] = arrayOne[i];
                ++i;
            }
            else {
                merged[k] = arrayOne[i];
                merged[k + 1] = arrayTwo[j];
                ++k;
                ++j;
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
    return merged;
}
```

This does not throw any exceptions until run time, where I get a type mismatch between
int[] and Comparable[]. The method must have two formal parameters of arrays of objects that implement the comparable interface. The method has to return an array of Comparable.

Answer (score 0):

The `int[]` type does not implement `Comparable`.   So you cannot use this method to merge two `int[]` objects.

Now I cannot see anywhere in the method that it would attempt to cast a `int[]` to a `Comparable[]` ... so we can only assume that the exception is actually being thrown by some other code.  The stacktrace would confirm this.

As to how to solve the *real* problem ... I don't know.  Because you haven't explained *why* you (apparently) want this method to work when it is called with `int[]` parameters.

---

It is also worth noting that you are not using the `Comparable` type correctly.  In fact, it is a generic type that looks like this

```
public interface <T> Comparable {
    public int compareTo(T t);
}
```

It says that the we can compare `this` which is a `T` with another instance of `T`.

You are using it as a *raw* type ... ignoring the type parameter `T`.  At the very least you should be getting compiler warnings about this.

To use it correctly, your method signature would need to look like this:

```
public <T extends Comparable> T[] mergeArrays(T[] arrayOne, T[] arrayTwo);
```

Then you have the problem of how to implement `new T[...]`.  That requires reflection and an extra `Class<T>` parameter.

```
public <T extends Comparable> T[] mergeArrays(
          T[] arrayOne, T[] arrayTwo, Class<T> clazz) {
    T[] result = Array.newInstance(clazz, arrayOne.length + arrayTwo.length);
    ...
```

---

In short, your code is problematic for Java 5 and later.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `<T extends Comparable<T>>`?